# Declaration of Array not accepted

Tags: java, arrays, declaration

I am creating a class that will play the role of a computer player in a virtual game of sticks. However, when I use the constructor method for this class, I lose the array that I have created, even though I had already declared the array in the state attributes. After 20 minutes, I am completely lost.

I am new to Java, and am trying to learn and get better. Any help would really be appreciated.
Below is the redesigned AI class along with the error that `Eclipse` keeps on submitting.

```
public class RedesignedAI {

private int[][] largeArray;
private int AIChoiceStick;
private Random random = new Random();
private int CurrentScore[] = new int[51]; //at max, if 100 sticks are initially chosen, then each player takes at max 50 sticks, 
private int h = 0;                                                                         //^so why not have one more in case



public RedesignedAI(int NumberSticks) //this is a constructor method and creates the arrays that contains a
{
    largeArray[][] = new int[NumberSticks][3];
    int i = 0;
    while(i < NumberSticks) 
    {    
        largeArray[i][0] = 1;      //ADD THIS
        largeArray[i][1] = 1;
        largeArray[i][2] = 1;
        i++;
    }     
}
```

The error: `largeArray` cannot be resolved to a type.

Answer (score 1):

You initialized the `largeArray`the wrong way. Use:

```
largeArray = new int[NumberSticks][3];
```

That `new` allocate a 2D array, so types are coherent both sides of the `=`.

If you want to allocate chunk by chunk then you should use `[]` syntax:

```
largeArray = new int[NumberSticks][]; // array of NumberSticks entries to array of int (not yet determined)
for (int i=0; i<NumberSticks; i++) {
  largeArray[i] = new int[3]; // i-th entry of array largeArray is a new array of 3 ints
}
```

`largeArray` is a reference to array of reference to array of `int`s. `largeArray[i]` is a reference to array of `int`s. `largeArray[i][j]`is an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private int[][] largeArray = null;
```

Initially initialize with null.
then in constructor

```
largeArray[][] = new int[3][3];
```

Since value is dynamic and you are changing it anyhow

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Any other possible solutions? I have absolutely no idea at this point. Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: Hmm... have to tried both I mean the way I see it int[][] largeArray = null might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the `array` on the top:

```
private int[][] largeArray = new int[x][y];
```

An `array` always has a fixed length. Only a `list` can variate the length.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
largeArray[][] = new int[NumberSticks][3];
```

into this:

```
largeArray = new int[NumberSticks][3];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `[][]` in the largeArray code of the constructor. This will do:

```
largeArray = new int[NumberSticks][3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong Code:
**largeArray[][] = new int[NumberSticks][3];**

Instead use:
**largeArray = new int[NumberSticks][3];**

Answer (score 0):

You may find it easier to use ArrayList instead. Maybe something like this:

```
private List<List<Integer>> largeArray;

...

public RedesignedAI(int NumberSticks) {

    largeArray = new ArrayList<>();

    int i = 0;

    while(i < NumberSticks) {

        List<Integer> innerArray = new ArrayList<>();

        innerArray.add(1);
        innerArray.add(1);
        innerArray.add(1);

        largeArray.add(innerArray); 

        i++;
    }
}
```